# xpath, start with (text) and following until

Tags: xpath, startswith

I have the following html structure:

```
<p><b> Some bold text which starts with xy <b>
<p> text
<p> text
<p><b> Next bold text <b>
<p> text
<p> text
```

I need to construct an xpath which grasps all text after the bold text which starts with xy ONLY until the next bold text which does not start with xy. My attempts so far:

```
"//p/*[starts-with(text()),'xy']/following::text()"
```

Yet, this grasps all text - also that after the next bold text which does not start with xy. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to get. Hope it help you: `//p[b[starts-with(.,'xy')]]/following::*[preceding::p[b][1]/b[starts-with(.,'xy')]]/text()`

Comment: @splash58 Thanks for your suggestions, I tried it - yet, the problem is still that also this xpath grasps all text in p, including those after the next bold p which does not start with xy. What I need is something which grasps only the text in p which comes after each bold p which starts with xy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution which seems to work:

```
"//p/b[starts-with(.,'xy')]/following::p[count(preceding::b) = 1]"
```

So, the trick is here the counter. The trade-off is that by setting the counter for all preceding b at 1, it will not go further than the first b after the b which starts with xy, yet, it also includes the text in that b. This can certainly be improved but it is ok for my purposes now.